# MacBook Pro Mid 2012 DDR3L Memory

Tags: macbook-pro, ddr3

I have a mid 2012 Macbook Pro 15" (model number A1286). Does this device support 2x4 GB of DDR3L 1600MHz RAM? (Please note the L in DDR3L :) )

Comment: Have you checked the Apple website?

Comment: Yep.. It says DDR3 1600MHz, not DDR3L...

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found this discussion on the Apple forum: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4026784?start=0&tstart=0

It seems like all the new MBPros have installed DDR3L memory and provide 1.35V voltage.